# iOS Swift - WKWebview how to open a web view based on target='_top'

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Hello I have a requirement to open a web page in safari browser when the page code is like this - target="_top". I have seen many stack overflow answers to open target="_blank" but not any other value. I am using WKWebview in my project
Please suggest how to do this